# Rcpp Makevars related warning

Tags: gnu-make, rcpp, r-package, compiler-flags

I am the mantainer of few R packages that use Rcpp for some core calculations. Wishing to try a new feature of the Rcpp package as described in [Rcpp 0.12.18 Rbloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/boost-the-speed-of-r-calls-from-rcpp/)

To do so I did the following:

1. I created a Makevars and Makevars.win in my **scr** folder, both contaning the line `CPPFLAGS += -DRCPP_USE_UNWIND_PROTECT`
2. I added the SystemRequirements: GNU make entry in the **DESCRIPTION** file.

Btw that raises some issues that I wounder will make my package rejected on CRAN:

1. following Warning message in compiling my package:

   - checking compilation flags in Makevars ... WARNING Variables overriding user/site settings: CPPFLAGS: -o /dev/null -DRCPP_USE_UNWIND_PROTECT
2. Note: GNU make is a system requirement

I would like to know if it is possible to rewrite the Makevars to remove the warning and possibly, the Gnu make requirement

Thanks in advance for the attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `PKG_CPPFLAGS` (or `PKG_CXXFLAGS`) as that is the *per-package variant*.  What you altered is the *system-wide version* hence the warning.

More details are as always in the Writing R Extensions manual, otherwise the *many* existing example packages (all on CRAN and browseable at GitHub) can help too.

For example, here is the one-toggle-setting use case from the RcppExamples package:

```
PKG_CXXFLAGS = -DRCPP_NEW_DATE_DATETIME_VECTORS
```

(which is strictly-speaking no longer needed as the "new" Date and Datetime vector classes became the default a while ago).

Also, if you use this form you do *not* need the `+=` and have no requirement to declare on GNU make -- another win.